# PDF to RTF File Converter

Tags: gratis, pdf, document-converter, rtf

I need a piece of software to convert a PDF file to an RTF file. It should preferably have a command-line interface or a GUI that supports batch-converting files. Windows is preferable but Linux is also OK. It must be free of charge.

Comment: Not shure, but UniPDF PDF to RTF Converter 1.3.3 could be helpful: https://unipdf-pdf-to-rtf-converter.soft112.com/